# Use python dict to lookup mutable objects

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a bunch of `File` objects, and a bunch of `Folder` objects. Each folder has a `list` of files. Now, sometimes I'd like to lookup which folder a certain file is in. I don't want to traverse over all folders and files, so I create a lookup `dict` file -> folder.

```
folder = Folder()
myfile = File()
folder_lookup = {}

# This is pseudocode, I don't actually reach into the Folder
# object, but have an appropriate method
folder.files.append(myfile)
folder_lookup[myfile] = folder
```

Now, the problem is, the files are mutable objects. My application is built around the fact. I change properites on them, and the GUI is notified and updated accordingly. Of course you can't put mutable objects in dicts. So what I tried first is to generate a hash based on the current content, basically:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.title, ...))
```

This didn't work of course, because when the object's contents changed its hash (and thus its identity) changed, and everything got messed up. What I need is an object that keeps its identity, although its contents change. I tried various things, like making `__hash__` return `id(self)`, overriding `__eq__`, and so on, but never found a satisfying solution. One complication is that the whole construction should be pickelable, so that means I'd have to store `id` on creation, since it could change when pickling, I guess.

So I basically want to use the identity of an object (not its state) to quickly look up data related to the object. I've actually found a really nice pythonic workaround for my problem, which I might post shortly, but I'd like to see if someone else comes up with a solution.

Comment: An attribute of the file object telling you in which folder they are is not an option?

Comment: Agreed with Jblasco. Try to have a unique attribute every time you create a new File object

Comment: @Jblasco: Yeah, that is the dead-simple pythonic workaround I went with :-). However, I'm still wondering if there is a way to do it with an external dict. One reason: There might be different classes of folders (directories, tags, smart searches). I'd have to add a special attribute for each kind.

Comment: Then the unique attribute could be a tuple like: ("Folder", "FolderType").

Comment: You could override `File`s `__str__` method so that it returns the file name and do `folder_lookup[str(myfile)] = folder`

Answer (score 0):

I felt dirty writing this. Just put folder as an attribute on the file.

```
class dodgy(list):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        super(list, self).__init__()
        self.store = type("store", (object,), {"blanket" : self})
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.store)

innocent_d = {}
dodge_1 = dodgy("dodge_1")
dodge_2 = dodgy("dodge_2")
innocent_d[dodge_1] = dodge_1.title
innocent_d[dodge_2] = dodge_2.title

print innocent_d[dodge_1]
dodge_1.extend(range(5))
dodge_1.title = "oh no"
print innocent_d[dodge_1]
```

Comment: That is very interesting, and I agree, pretty devious. Especially what you are putting into `store`. However, I never needed the File / dodgy object to be a list subclass. If it's a regular object subclass, apparently one can just use it as a key if one is careful.

Comment: Yes, I chose a list object just to demonstrate it with an unhashable type.

Answer (score 0):

OK, everybody noticed the extremely obvious workaround (that took my some days to come up with), just put an attribute on `File` that tells you which folder it is in. (Don't worry, that is also what I did.)

But, it turns out that I was working under wrong assumptions. You are not supposed to use mutable objects as keys, but that doesn't mean you can't (diabolic laughter)! The default implementation of `__hash__` returns a unique value, probably derived from the object's address, that remains constant in time. And the default `__eq__` follows the same notion of object identity.

So you can put mutable objects in a dict, and they work as expected (if you expect equality based on instance, not on value).

See also: [I'm able to use a mutable object as a dictionary key in python. Is this not disallowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418741/im-able-to-use-a-mutable-object-as-a-dictionary-key-in-python-is-this-not-disa)

I was having problems because I was pickling/unpickling the objects, which of course changed the hashes. One could generate a unique ID in the constructor, and use that for equality and deriving a hash to overcome this.

(For the curious, as to why such a "lookup based on instance identity" dict might be neccessary: I've been experimenting with a kind of ["object database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126776/query-language-for-python-objects). You have pure python objects, put them in lists/containers, and can define indexes on attributes for faster lookup, complex queries and so on. For foreign keys (1:n relationships) I can just use containers, but for the backlink I have to come up with something clever if I don't want to modify the objects on the *n* side.)